# MySQL select not equal to limit in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit

MySQL #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Given 1 table as following

```
Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
1    | Adidas     | 310.00
2    | Nike Run   |  30.00
3    | Puma       | 150.00
4    | Nike Women |  20.00
5    | NB         |  20.00
```

Would like to select records and return the sum amount. Do not sum up the 2 highest prices' record.

```
SELECT SUM(Price) as total_amount
FROM `test`
WHERE Item NOT IN (
    SELECT Price 
    FROM `test`
    ORDER BY Price DESC
    LIMIT 2)
```

Expected Result:

```
total_amount
------------
   70.00
```

How to use JOIN or alternative LIMIT in Subquery in this query?

Thank you.

Comment: I think your subquery has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using a subquery with  `limit / offset`:

```
select sum(price)
from (
  select *
  from test
  order by price desc
  limit 999999999
  offset 2
  ) t
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a52b/1)

Just make sure the limit value is greater than the number of potential rows (which evidently is 18446744073709551615)...

Or you could use `user-defined variables`:

```
select sum(price)
from (
  select *, @rn:=@rn + 1 rn
  from test cross join (select @rn:= 0) t
  ) t
where rn > 2
```

---

If you looking to exclude the 2 highest prices which could be more than 2 records, this will also work with `user defined variables`:

```
select sum(price)
from (
  select *, @rn:=if(@prevPrice=price, @rn,
                    if(@prevPrice:=price, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)) rn
  from test cross join (select @rn:= 0, @prevPrice:= null) t
  ) t
where rn > 2
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea254/1)

Comment: @sgeddes..when there are ties for the maximum value..this query would include the second max value in the sum.

Comment: @vkp -- good point, perhaps needs to be better defined by the OP.

Comment: @vkp -- edited with an alternative solution for both options using `user-defined variables`...

Answer (score 1):

You need a temp table:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) FROM test WHERE Item NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Item FROM test ORDER BY Price DESC LIMIT 2
    ) AS tmp
)
```